# curl function or send grid email api not running on my server

Tags: php, email, curl, sendgrid

i was using this code previously for sending the email:

```
    <?php

   $tos='sonam2@gmail.com';
  $subject09='hello madam223';
  $messageto90='this is a test';
  $myName_emailis='Sonam ';
 $emaillist_act=array('Sonam@gmail.com','sakshiprakas@gmail.com');
 $json_string = array( 'to' =>$emaillist_act,'category' => 'activity');

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
 $user = 'username';
 $pass = 'password';
 $params = array(
'api_user'  => $user,
'api_key'   => $pass,
'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($json_string),
'to'        => "$tos",
'subject'   => "$subject09",
'html'      => "$messageto90",
'fromname' => $myName_emailis,
'from'      => "domain.com <contact@domain.com>"
 );
 $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';
 // Generate curl request
 $session = curl_init($request);
 // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
@curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
print_r($response);
?>
```

But now the same code doesn't do anything. Neither it prints the response nor it sends the email.

I thought that might be curl is not installed on my server so i checked it by a curl function and

```
 function _is_curl_installed() {
if  (in_array  ('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}
```

And it shows me true ..

What could be the possible reason? please help me.
it is still printing the success message on other server and not on my server what may be the issue ??

Comment: please check this link I think there are some changes with the paramater https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/php.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending the api userid ,api key in the api url itself. And curl doesnt require separate definition.I'd used following code to fetch json data it worked.

```
$json_url = "https://httpapi.com/api/products/reseller-price.json?auth-userid";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json_url);

$str = curl_exec($ch);

$ar = json_decode($str,true);

  echo $ar['domcno'][0]['pricing']['addnewdomain'][1];
```

Comment: i cant change code as the same code is there in many domains and all my domais are hosted on the same server .. so i need to fix the issue from server end

Comment: Was the code working initially?and is it just now you're facing the issue? Did you try sending mails by changing from "mail" field to just from "name" ?May be the gmail is rejecting the mails because the from field containing domain.com.I'd faced some similar issue yesterday so just trying to help you. Though I'm just a beginner and yet to do in depth study in web developing. But I do hope you get required help you're looking for here.

Comment: I edited my above comment. If the same code works, why don't you do proper line by line comparing and checking of the code.